# Replace selection with new content

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have a list (but I have table cells):

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li class="middle">2</li>
    <li class="middle">3</li>
    <li class="middle">3</li>
    <li>last</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to replace all the `.middle` elements with one `<li>middle</li>`. Using jQuery's `replaceWith` would replace all individual elements (as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9vm7dcr/)):

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>new content</li>
    <li>new content</li>
    <li>new content</li>
    <li>last</li>
</ul>
```

but I want this:

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>new content</li>
    <li>last</li>
</ul>
```

Is there native jQuery method to do this, or I have to create new list (or new table row) in my case, than to remove old and add new?

Please note: all the elements are sequential, in DOM tree they go one after another (they are a group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap them all within `<li>middle</li>`, then remove them:

```js
$('li.middle').wrapAll('<li>middle</li>').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li class="middle">2</li>
  <li class="middle">3</li>
  <li class="middle">3</li>
  <li>last</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, using the jQuery's method return value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**removeClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and [**:first**](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```js
$('.middle:not(:first)').remove();
$('.middle').removeClass('middle').text('New content');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li class="middle">2</li>
  <li class="middle">3</li>
  <li class="middle">3</li>
  <li>last</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough: I want to replace the group of `.middle` list elements with some **new** content, as `<li>some new content</li>`. The 'middle' class is just a helper that exists. I could go with `$('.middle').before( ..new element ) than remove()`, just asking if there is some existing jQuery method.

Comment: @skobaljic, I dont think theres a utility method that exists to do what your after. You will just have to do it manually

Comment: Think Rick's solution uses jQuery methods in correct way, so I do not have to do it manually. Thanks Ammar for your time.

Comment: @skobaljic, Ricks solution is good. But think about it, you are still doing it manually, even if its in a minimal manner :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.middle').each(function() {
    if ($('.middle').length == 1) {
        $(this).replaceWith('<p>New content</p>');
        return;
    }
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Yes, one of the solutions, but still one that I try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

`replaceWith` accepts function parameter - as such you can replace the first occurence of found element, and discard the rest:

```
$(".middle").replaceWith(function(index){ return index == 0 ? "<li>new content</li>" : " "});
```